# Issue updating google contacts from javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-contacts-api

I am using [unirest](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html) in nodejs to send a PUT request to update the contacts.

```
unirest.put(url)
    .header({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+result.profileData.split('?access_token=')[1],
        'If-Match': '*',
    })
    .send({"entry":{"phoneNumber":req.body.mobile}})
    .end(function (res1) {
        res.send(res1);
    });
}
```

I am getting response: `Object {statusCode: 415, body: "Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not a valid input type.", headers: Object, request: Object}`

I am sending the data as `.send({"entry":{"phoneNumber":req.body.mobile}})` and I am not sure this is the correct format?

I didn't find any [documentation on this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#updating_contacts) based on javascript. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to provide a Content type header. So add it to the object passed into the .headers method with a value of json/application

```
...
.headers({
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  ...
})
...
```

Comment: Its updating now but setting the contact number to empty

Comment: Whats your error message? Also, you can typically can find out the correct request body format from the API documentation of the API with which you are interacting. Or read the source code of the API if accessible.

Comment: API documentation is very bad